# Convert MP4 to AMV Faster? ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Here is the code a buddy got for me that I'm using.

`-c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf "scale=296:256:force_original_aspect_ratio:flags=lanczos,crop=256:in_h:20:0,pad=320:256:64:-1:color=black" -vstrict -1 -r 18 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -block_size 1225`

I wanted to know of anyone has any idea how I could go about making the conversion go quicker.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So [this is your target codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMV_video_format)? Highly unlikely you could speed this up.

Comment: `how I could go about making the conversion go quicker` better hardware would work